# How to find files that contain two or more of a specific character?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wildcard

I'm learning about wildcards and I'm trying to figure out how to find filenames that contain a specific character, two or more times.

For example, finding filenames that have two or more `x`'s in them, such as *Xerox*.

I know how to find files that have an *x, or that have an *ox*, but I can't figure out how I'd find a file named Xerox.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more examples? This question is unclear to me.

Comment: Suppose I have a directory with 2 files: xerox, xero, and xxerox. I can use ls *x to get a list of all three of them, or ls *xxx\* to get xxxerox. But I want to know how to get just xerox, by virtue of the fact that it has two or more x's.

Comment: The reason that the question is unclear to me is that technically, `ls | grep xerox` answers your question but I am pretty sure that is not what you are looking for. I **assume** what you need to look into are regular expressions. http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Xerox was just an example. What I'm trying to find are files that contain two or more x's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding files that contain two or more `x`'s, you want to use a regular expression.

`ls | egrep x.*x` is an example.

[Take a look at this Regular Expression cheatsheet.](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) This will work because you match a single `x`, followed by 0 or more of any character (represented by `.*`), followed by another `x`.

Comment: Ah I see, I wouldn't have figured out the concatenation of the two rules. Thanks